# How to get position of TextView which is visible for user

Tags: android

I am trying to get the position of scrollable textview. Show if user again land on this screen textview should be visible from that place where he leave from previous task.

Comment: You have to take the `TextView` as child of `ScrollView` then you can get the `ScrollView` position as `scrollView.getScrollY()`.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of Textview position you can directly store the Scroll view position it self and use it further for your convinence.

Like

- Call your_scrollview.getScrollY() on the ScrollView.
- Store it for your further usage

Next time when you visited the place take the stored scroll view position and call the below mehtod.

```
 your_scrollview.scrollTo(0, your stored value);
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try this:

```
int[] locations = new int[2];
textview.getLocationOnScreen(locations);
int x = locations[0];
int y = locations[1];
```

Answer (score 0):

i advise you to use a ListView with that method setOnItemClickListener()

Answer (score 0):

try this method

```
private Rect locateView(TextView v)
        {
            int[] loc_int = new int[2];
            if (v == null) return null;
            try
            {
                v.getLocationOnScreen(loc_int);
            } catch (NullPointerException npe)
            {
                //Happens when the view doesn't exist on screen anymore.
                return null;
            }
            Rect location = new Rect();
            location.left = loc_int[0];
            location.top = loc_int[1];
            location.right = location.left + v.getWidth();
            location.bottom = location.top + v.getHeight();
            return location;
        }
```